# Easiest way to get Perfmon counter names into a text file?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, perfmon, logman

I'd like to create a settings file for my logman command. I expect to have lots of perfmon counters.

Is there any easy way to get all the perfmon counters' exact text anywhere?

The only thing I thought of was to create a Perfmon Counter Log through the GUI and then export the list of selected counters--but I don't see an export option!  I guess I could manually copy what I see on the screen, but that seems inefficient. I'm going to be dealing with tens of counters.

Maybe there is a list somewhere? That'd be easier to copy and paste from.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An easy way to achieve this, is by using the `typeperf` command.

1. For example, to get an complete list of all available Windows PerfMon counters is by typing the following command from a command prompt: `typeperf -q`
2. Create a file `counters.txt` with all the counters you would like to monitor, (1 per line)
3. send output to a logfile. (`typeperf -cf counters.txt -si 5 -sc 50 -f TSV -o domain2.tsv`)

Good luck!
Henk

Comment: Here's what I did: `typeperf -q -o "C:\Temp\counters.txt"`.  That sent all the counter names to a text file. And then it's trivial to build a logman script.  Thank you, @Henk!

Comment: You made my day.

Comment: Microsoft documentation link, for options/switches: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/typeperf

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've ever been able to do this is to set up your trace and then save it (or copy the properties and paste them to a text file).  The HTML or copied properties creates an `<object>` tag with a lot of `<param>` tags to set up the trace.  It's not very pretty, but you can use an XML parser to filter the `<param>` tags.  The counters have `NAME` attributes in the format `Counterxxxxx` (where the X's are incremental numbers with leading 0's) and a `Path` attribute that is the name of the target machine concantenated with the name of the counter.  Filter out those specific nodes and you'll get the list.

I don't know how you would go about just exporting a list of all available counters on your system.  Maybe WMI or Powershell has something you can get it from.

Also, have a look at [**this question**](https://serverfault.com/questions/24439/need-a-resource-that-lists-wmi-perfmon-classes) which might give you some more leads.

Answer (score 2):

You can export a list of all the services that have performance counters on a particular machine by querying the registry of said machine. From a command prompt type reg query /? to get a list of arguments.