# Zabbix monitoring system

Tags: networking, monitoring, performance-monitoring, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I want to monitor some things and I was wondering what of the following can be done using Zabbix easily, what can be done with some extra effort and what can't be done with it:

*All computers are running either Windows or Linux*

- Login/Logout of a computer
- Turning a computer on/off
- Interent connection
- Trigger network cable being disconnected
- CPU activity (broken down by programs)
- Visited websites
- Admin activity or failure of such activities
- Irregular killing of programs
- GPU activety
- Hardware Temaruture
- Disk faults
- RAM usage

If there are any good websites where I can find this type of information I'd love to hear about them.

Thanks.

Comment: http://zabbix.org/wiki/Main_Page <-- Have you read/reviewed this documentation?

Comment: I've been reading through that for a while... there is nothing there! To none of my questions does it answer...

Comment: If this is not the place for this kind of question then what is???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Login/Logout of a computer

  Sure, you can monitor # active connections, which will give you this.
- Turning a computer on/off

  Yes
- Interent connection

  Not sure what an interent connection is, but if you mean internet connection, then yes
- Trigger network cable being disconnected

  Sort of. If the NIC is unplugged though, Zabbix can't tell if it was unplugged or if the computer lost power, because it can't be contacted. If the monitored machine has more than one NIC, then yes, it can monitor connection statuses if the NIC that is still connected can communicate with Zabbix.
- CPU activity (broken down by programs)

  It can't break it down by process. But to be fair I've never seen any NMS do this.
- Visited websites

  No. This is something almost impossible to monitor at client level and can only be reliably be monitored at firewall level.
- Admin activity or failure of such activities

  Not sure what this means?
- Irregular killing of programs

  You mean you want to monitor the exit codes of programs? No.
- GPU activety

  If it's exposed in a Windows Performance Monitor counter, then yes. Otherwise, no.
- Hardware Temaruture

  If you mean temperature, then yes - *if* it's exposed by your motherboard and you enable SNMP or IPMI on your clients. I don't think this data is exposed via perfmons.
- Disk faults

  Yes
- RAM usage

  Would be pretty useless if it couldn't.

zabbix can monitor everything that is exposed by Windows Performance Monitors (+ loads more if configured correctly).

Want a full list of everything supported out of the box? [Check this question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/149816/easiest-way-to-get-perfmon-counter-names-into-a-text-file).

Comment: Admin activity: Sudo commands or the appropriate Windows equivelent

Comment: @nayish . . . combined with appropriate auditing, and something to relay the audit logs to Zabbix :)